Chat Engine not reactive - reload
My chat engine react components are not reactive as when i add a chat id doesnt show the new chat in the chat list and similiarly when i add new people in that the new members are only shown the refresh button is created
import ChatList2 from './ChatList'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import ChatFeed from './ChatList';
import Navbar from "../navbar"

export default function ChatRoom() {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const projectID="819a1503-c401-42af-ba29-96a83c02033d";
  const userName=user.email;
  const userSecret=user.firstname;
  return (
    <div >
      <Navbar/>
       <ChatEngine
        height="calc(100vh - 66px)"  // Corrected the CSS here
        projectID={projectID}
        userName={userName}
        userSecret={userSecret}
      /> 
    </div>
  );
}



